# Cannot seem to use must and must_not together in an elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

If I run the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "boxing",
                        "fuzziness": 2,
                        "minimum_should_match": 2
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "terms_set": {
                        "allowedCountries": {
                            "terms": ["gb", "mx"],
                            "minimum_should_match_script": {
                                "source": "2"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "expireTime": {
                            "gt": 1674061907954
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "region": {
                            "value": "row"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "sourceType": {
                            "value": "article"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

against an index with articles that look like:

```
{
    "_index": "content-items-v10",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "e7hm75ui4dma1mm4j8q5v7914",
    "_score": 4.3724976,
    "_source": {
        "allowedCountries": ["gb", "ie"],
        "body": "Both Joshua Buatsi and Craig Richards join The DAZN Boxing Show ahead of their clash at London's O2 Arena. Matchroom's Eddie Hearn also gives his take on the night, as well as Chantelle Cameron previewing her contest with Victoria Noelia Bustos.",
        "competitions": [
            {
                "id": "8lo6205qyio0fksjx9glqbdhj",
                "name": "Buatsi v Richards"
            }
        ],
        "contestants": [
            {
                "id": "7rq59j3eiamxlm12vhxcsgujj",
                "name": "Joshua Buatsi"
            },
            {
                "id": "boby9oqe23g6qyuwphrxh8su5",
                "name": "Craig Richards"
            }
        ],
        "countries": [
            {
                "id": "7yasa43laq1nb2e6f8bfuvxed",
                "name": "World"
            },
            {
                "id": "258l9t5sm55592i08mdpqzr3t",
                "name": "United Kingdom"
            }
        ],
        "dotsLastUpdateTime": 1673979749396,
        "expireTime": 4800000000000,
        "fixtureDate": {},
        "headline": "Buatsi vs. Richards: Preview",
        "id": "e7hm75ui4dma1mm4j8q5v7914",
        "importance": 0,
        "languageKeys": ["en"],
        "languages": ["en"],
        "lastUpdateTime": {
            "ts": 1653088281000,
            "iso8601": "2022-05-20T23:11:21.000Z"
        },
        "promoImageUrl": null,
        "publication": {
            "typeId": "1plcw0iyhx9vn1fcanbm2ja3rf",
            "typeName": "Shoulder"
        },
        "publishedTime": {
            "ts": 1653088281000,
            "iso8601": "2022-05-20T23:11:21.000Z"
        },
        "region": "row",
        "shortHeadline": null,
        "sourceType": "article",
        "sports": [
            {
                "id": "2x2oqzx60orpoeugkd754ga17",
                "name": "Boxing"
            }
        ],
        "teaser": "",
        "thumbnailImageUrl": "https://images.daznservices.com/di/library/babcock_canada/45/3e/the-dazn-boxing-show-20052022_xc4jbfqi022l1shq9lu641h9e.png?t=-477976832",
        "translations": {}
    }
}
```

I get the following validation error from elasticsearch:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "errors": {
        "validation": [
            {
                "message": "\"query.bool.must_not\" is not allowed",
                "path": [
                    "query",
                    "bool",
                    "must_not"
                ],
                "type": "object.unknown",
                "context": {
                    "child": "must_not",
                    "label": "query.bool.must_not",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "terms_set": {
                                "allowedCountries": {
                                    "terms": [
                                        "gb",
                                        "mx"
                                    ],
                                    "minimum_should_match_script": {
                                        "source": "2"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "key": "must_not"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "correlationId": "d29e9275-9ab3-4ff8-944d-852b98d4b503"
}
```

And I cannot figure out what the issue might be! From the elastic docs it should be OK.

I'm using ElasticSearch 7.9.3 running in a local docker container.

I'm hoping someone out there will give me a clue!

Cheers!

I would expect this to just work.

I'm trying to filter out articles that have both of the country codes `gb` and `mx` in the field `allowedCountries`.

I can include them easily enough in the results when I add the `terms_set` query to the `bool.must` section of the query.

Comment: I get results with your query. You put the query inside " { "query": { "bool": ... } }?

Comment: Sorry @rabbitbr I did not see your comment before posting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works well, you just need to enclose your query in the `query` section

```
{
    "query": {        <--- add this 
       "bool": {      <--- your query starts here
          "must": [
      ...
```

Comment: Ah, dammit, I didn't copy the whole thing - I have that at the start of my query - sorry - I'll update my question. I chopped out a bit too much when I cleaned up the log I had for presentation here.

Comment: Still works for me... are you sure this is the exact query you're running? Where are you taking it from? From the error, it looks like you have two nested must_not queries

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding!

I was helping with a system I did not have full context on - it turns out there is a proxy in the mix with validation that was blocking the `must_not` query. So, with the proxy fixed, it now works.